# http send get request and catch the response

Tags: php, http, get, request, response

I am programming some code which send .... I have no idea how to describe this, cause I am not a full time php programmer and the technologies and frameworks are developing very fast.

so, I have a code... well, address:

```
http://www.something.sk/something/CID=username&VS=012345&RURL=xxx
```

where xxx is some dress where I can catch response from that server, but it make no sense for me if i will be using, but it should be not blank

```
file_get_contents(url_above)
```

so, my questions are:

1) how to do this?
2) Where '?' was lost from that request url, if the api wants http form style get method arguments which looks like /index.php?id=blahblah&VS=012345 but it is it not working this way.
3) when I hard type the url above to the browser url bar, it gives me an error:

```
Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI:
```

which makes no sense. Also, I am not the owner of the server, and the response should be like:

```
STATUS=ok&CODE=687629
```

4) so, once again, how to code it properly to send and catch response? Or how to even find on the google, cause I have no idea how to name it. I have seen some posts and php doc, but they are using 'file_get_contents' method as the safest

Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: Could you alaborate a bit more on what you're trying to acomplish? it seems a little bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: hmmm, it is fuzzy to me too, but I want to catch response from the server which is accepting get-method requests.

Comment: if you mean that you want to for example get the "CID" value from the GET request, you can do in PHP: $cid = $_GET['CID'];

Answer (score 0):

i have'nt fully understood your question,but here's my answer:
Have you stored the values in a database?
if so,use the id of a value in the `xxx` part of the address.
also, if the user enters an id that does'nt exists,use `try/catch`(or something else like showing an error.html page) to show the user the appropriate error so they wont get confused.
if you are linking the product in an `<a>` tag,it should look like this:

```
<a href:"http://www.something.sk/something/CID=username&VS=012345&RURL='id comes here'">Dress</a>
```

if this did'nt help you,please feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this, you're sending a page request to the server, not a get request.
you can help this by changing your url from:

```
    http://www.something.sk/something/CID=username&VS=012345&RURL=xxx
```

to

```
    http://www.something.sk/something?CID=username&VS=012345&RURL=xxx
```

then in PhP to get the files (i see you're using Kohana so if you're using 3.3)

```
    $cid = $this->request->get('cid');
    $vs = $this->request->get('vs');
    $rurl = $this->request->get('rurl');
```

or if you're not using kohana :

```
    $cid = $_GET['cid'];
    $vs = $_GET['vs'];
    $rurl = $_GET['rurl'];
```